# Find all "null" values using xquery

Tags: sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, xquery

I was tasked to find all values where `<nodeA>` is empty. That could mean that it is NULL, or that it doesn't exist.

I have crafted the below query

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE AttributeList.value ('(/AttributeList/nodeA)[1]', 'varchar(50)') IS NULL
```

However it returns only results that look like `<AttributeList />`

What I am curious of is would this also return an XML that looked like

```
<AttributeList>
    <nodeA></nodeA>
</AttributeList>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to extract the values from the XML. Use [exist](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx) instead.

```sql
select *
from YourTable 
where AttributeList.exist('/AttributeList/nodeA/node()') = 0
```

Comment: so `/AttributeList/nodeA` makes sense to me. But what would I be filling in for `node()`? And would the 0 be if there was actually a 0 in that node, or could it be `IS NULL`?

Comment: @mhopkins321 you should not replace node() with anything. It looks for a node of any kind. 0 means that there are no nodes found. If there where nodes found the return value from exist is 1 regardless of how many nodes matched the expression.

Comment: hmmm, when I run this I get both `<AttributeList />` (correct to return) as well as `<AttributeList><nodeA>value1</nodeA></AttributeList>` (not correct to return)

Comment: @mhopkins321 Have a look at this [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/62d45/1) does it not do what you want?

Comment: Man, that is very confusing. That is exactly what I want, yet it doesn't work for me. Got it to work. was doing the equivalent of `nodea` instead of the correct `nodeA`

Comment: @mhopkins321 Yes that explains things. XML is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fn:empty(...)` to check whether there are any children. Remember to handle both attributes and other nodes (elements, text nodes, ...) if needed.

```
//*[empty( (./node(), ./attribute()) )]
```

[W3schools.com has a nice overview on axis steps](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_axes.asp) if you want to redefine "empty".